# Makefile source within wildcard

Tags: makefile, wildcard

I don't know how to make a dependence rule within * inside
as: folder1/folder2/*/sch.oa
to the target:
folder3/*.scs

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Do you mean you want a rule such that when you `make folder3/foo.scs`, it will seek the prerequisite `folder1/folder2/foo/sch.oa`?

Comment: yes exactly, folder3/foo.scs depending folder1/folder2/foo/sch.oa !

Answer (score 0):

Just write a [pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Rules):

```
folder3/%.scs: folder1/folder2/%/sch.oa
    @echo building $@ from $<
```

**EDIT:** to build all such files, first find all such `sch.oa` files:

```
SOURCES := $(wildcard folder1/folder2/*/sch.oa)
```

then calculate the corresponding targets:

```
TARGETS := $(patsubst folder1/folder2/%/sch.oa,folder3/%.scs, $(SOURCES))
```

Then you can write a simple rule that has them as its prerequisites.

Comment: it doesn't work I have this error: make: *** No targets.  Stop.

Comment: @Oli013: That's if you try `make`. If you specify the target (e.g. `make folder3/foo.scs`), it'll work, provided the prerequisite file exists. Would you like it to build all possible targets, by default (i.e. with `make`)?

Comment: Yes I would like to make all folder1/folder2/%/sch.oa occurrences for folder3/%.scs target !